# windows environment, the command line, can not run shell script? To run, how to run?

Tags: shell

windows environment, the command line, can not run shell script? To run, how to run?

Comment: @Sunil Thanks for the reminder, however, your reply also exposed what I want to hide

Comment: Now everyone will know. >:-)

Comment: ifaas-update is not compatible with sh, especially in Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solutions, in the most-to-least reasonable order:

`0`. Install any Linux-based OS (https://www.archlinux.org is one example of several hundreds available).

1.1. Install [MSYS2](http://www.msys2.org/).

1.2. If you're on Windows 10, turn on [the so-called Developer Mode](https://www.howtogeek.com/292914/what-is-developer-mode-in-windows-10/).

Positive-numbered options will also require some additional actions, like installing ConEmu and, probably, any X Server implementation for Windows.

I haven't listed somewhat less frequently used options like installing any BSD, OpenSolaris or any other Unix-like OS, these options would not add much information here.

Comment: I think, only the case, ```win10``` upload```linux``` virtual machine to run the ```shell script```

Comment: Do you mean install a Linux in a VM? Well, that's the one more option, still reasonable. Last time I needed a running Windows, some 6 years ago, I did the reverse: a WinXP in a VirtualBox under Debian.
Note that the DevMode actually installs a special subdistro of Ubuntu on your Win machine, kernel then run as a user-space process (though DevMode has its own pitfalls: one sunny day your whole filesystem becomes unreachable from Linux processes, then, as some kind of recovery mode, you spend a few hours on moving the files to another dir in Windows Explorer and then copying them back in bash.)